# Why are there multiple LUKS partitions?

Tags: luks, cryptsetup

I'm new to using LUKS. After installing it on `/dev/sda` successfully I don't understand what the `/dev/sda1, /dev/sda2` partitions on the HDD represent. I expect to see the only one encrypted partition.

Before decryption, `/dev/sda` has the structure:

```
❯ lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1                   8:1    0 168.8G  0 part
└─sda2                   8:2    0 717.4G  0 part
```

After decryption:

```
❯ sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sda silverbox
❯ lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1                   8:1    0 168.8G  0 part
├─sda2                   8:2    0 717.4G  0 part
└─silverbox            253:3    0   1.8T  0 crypt

❯ lsblk --fs
NAME                   FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                    crypto_LUKS       42a9febd-2d7b-4c12-b92a-4e1ec6a1b5a5
├─sda1
├─sda2
└─silverbox            ext4              b692ba9b-ad36-4689-9b17-5b03af684130      1.6T     7% /media/vol/b692ba9b-ad36-4689-9b17-5b03af684130
```

`silverbox` is a 1.8TB dedicated data partition. What is the purpose of the `168.8G` and `717,4G` partitions?

And why isn't their total size 1.8TB?

Comment: Do you have created a filesystem on `sda1` or `sda2`? If you don't know, you can use `lsblk --fs` to get this information.

Comment: I installled LUKS on `/dev/sda` and ext4 FS on the `silverbox` container

Comment: How did you install LUKS on `sda`? In your case i would think you did something like `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda`. Did you use any helper script, in addition to `cryptsetup`?

Comment: Exactly the command you wrote above. No additional scripts.

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**disk usage**

You ask why the total size of `sda1` and `sda2` is not 1800 gigabyte. The answer is, that the disk space hasn't been used completely for the partitions.

- `sda` is the whole disk. The size is 1800 gigabyte.
- `sda1` is the 1st partition of `sda`. The size is 169 gigabyte.
- `sda2` is the 2nd partition of `sda`. The size is 718 gigabyte.
- `sda` has about 913 gigabyte unused space left.

The person or software that created the partitions, decided to leave some space unused. But this has nothing to do with LUKS or `cryptsetup`, this is only about splitting a disk into partitions.

> silverbox is 1.8T size decaoded data partition

No. The smaller sized `sda1` and `sda2` are partitions, but `silverbox` isn't a partition.

**cryptsetup**

The command `cryptsetup open /dev/sda silverbox` opens (creates a mapping with) `silverbox` backed by device `/dev/sda`. The size of the physical device (`sda`) is 1800 gigabyte, and therefore the size of the logical device (`silverbox`) is also 1800 gigabyte.

Using `cryptsetup open` with LUKS works only on disks or partitions, if they are already LUKS formatted. To do this, you can use `cryptsetup luksFormat`.

**Where do the partitions come from?**

You say that `sda1, sda2` were created automatically during LUKS installation. I want to believe you, but i'm 99% sure that `cryptsetup luksFormat` doesn't create partitions.

If you want to manage `sda` as a whole, you don't need these partitions anyway. They look like "ghost partitions" to me, they shouldn't even exist.

**How to get rid of the "ghost partitions"?**

If you don't have any valuable data on the disk, i would just delete the partitions and then reformat the disk. Reformat might be unnecessary, but i can't predict how deleting the partitions will affect the disk's content. Just make sure that nothing on `sda` is open or mounted before you start.

You can delete the partitions with a tool like `parted`. Then again:

- `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda`
- `cryptsetup open /dev/sda silverbox`
- `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/silverbox`

After that, you should have the full disk capacity available, without any partitions.

**Why is the LUKS container size bigger than the total size of the two partitions?**

The first paragraph "disk usage" was supposed to clarify this topic, but i want to address this questions in particular.

The size of the LUKS container has the same size as the disk, because cryptsetup was told to (LUKS-)format the whole disk. The partitions are smaller, because they have been created like this.

You seem to see a relation between the (existence of the) partitions and what cryptsetup does/did. But i'm pretty sure there is no such relation. The partitions are not LUKS partitions, they are just partitions.

Comment: A few facts. `sda1, sda2` were created automatically during LUKS installation, i don't know why not one and would like to figure it out. The size of these partitions was set up automatically and i also would like to understand why.  


Seems i'm wrong in terminology and asked the incorrect question. For now, it should be why the container size is bigger than the total one of two partitions?

Comment: @r45i i rewrote my answer.

Comment: Great. I'll reformat the disk again to get rid off those partitions. I thought the container is based on them somehow.